# Where does Vocal 2.0 save downloaded podcasts?

Tags: release-freya, files, download

I really have no idea, I can't find the source files anywhere on and Vocal says that it has downloaded them.

Answer (score 2):

On my system (which is Ubuntu and vocal 1.0), it is in `~/.local/share/vocal`

Answer (score 1):

I believe they should be in `~/vocal` (or `~/.vocal`).